# Query object with Subject (angularfire2)

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I wanted to know if it possible to have a service which provides and firebase object which url is bind to a subject, this is my current setup:

**Homie.Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class HomieService {
  homies: FirebaseListObservable<Homie[]>;
  homie: FirebaseObjectObservable<Homie>;
  public subject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.subject = new BehaviorSubject('');
    this.homies = db.list('/homies');
    this.homie = db.object('/homies/' + this.subject.value);
  }
}
```

This is the service which "Provides" an object which has its URL bind to a subject.

Right now I have a component that does this:

**Homie-list.component**

```
  selectHomie(selected: any) {
    this.homieService.subject.next(selected);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard/homies/list/detail');
  }
```

Where "selected" is the key of the object which I want to retrieve

And another component (the one that loads because of the router) which has this code :

**Homie-detail.component**

```
export class HomieDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  homie: any;
  constructor(private homieService: HomieService, private serviceService: ServiceService, private router: Router) {
    this.homieService = homieService;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.homie = this.homieService.homie;
  }
}
```

Right now nothing happens, this.homie its just an empty object.

I have tried many variations like:

Adding a subscribe to this.homie in the Home-detail.component:

```
  this.homieService.homie.subscribe(res => {
      this.homie = res;
    });
```

(This does nothing)

Using Subject or BehaviorSubject (without the .value) on the service:

```
  public subject: Subject<any>;
  constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.subject = new Subject('');
    this.homie = db.object('/homies/' + this.subject);
  }
}
```

or

```
this.homie = db.object('/homies/' + this.subject);
```

But these two, because subjects are objects don't work.

Answer (score 0):

`Subject` doesn't keep current value, it just pass new value to subscribers.

According to your question, Here you can use `BehaviorSubject` which keeps the current value and also provides a method `getValue()` which you can use to get Current value from it, see [docs](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/behaviorsubject.md#rxbehaviorsubjectprototypegetvalue).

```
public subject: BehaviorSubject<any>;
constructor(db: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.subject = new BehaviorSubject('');
  this.homie = db.object('/homies/' + this.subject.getValue());  // get current value from BehaviorSubject
}
```

Here is a **[Plunder demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/kORLv4gVjVbXCmIAZVJu?p=preview)** to demonstrate.